# Passing variables from within VueJS components

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, laravel-5

I am new to VueJs and Laravel. I am trying to build a chat app following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNIqJcvt6PI&list=PLJpBh2VJhy5x2GKfkfIcn0r6P6uLat7xR&index=2) tutorial, and my problem is that I am not able to pass a **CONTACT** variable (object type) from ChatApp.vue to Conversation.vue. The console gives this error

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "contact". Expected Object, got Null 
found in ---> <MessageFeed> at resources/js/officer/components/MessageFeed.vue
   <Conversation> at resources/js/officer/components/Conversation.vue
     <ChatApp> at resources/js/officer/components/ChatApp.vue
       <Root>
```

first the variable has to pass through ChatApp to Conversation and then to MessageFeed. I tried printing it on console, in ChatApp.vue, it printed the variable's property i.e. name but when I try to print it in Conversation.vue, it says it is null and also gives the above error.

please see the code below:

**ChatApp.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="chat-app">
    <Conversation :contact="selectedContact" :messages="messages" @new="saveNewMessage"/>
    <ContactsList :contacts="contacts" @selected="startConversationWith"/>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import Conversation from "./Conversation";
import ContactsList from "./ContactsList";
const axios = require('axios');
export default {
    props: {
        user: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            selectedContact: null,
            messages: [],
            contacts: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        Echo.private(`messages.${this.user.id}`)
            .listen('NewMessage', (e) => {
                this.handleIncoming(e.message);
            });
        console.log(this.user);
        axios.get('/officer/contacts')
            .then((response) => {
                this.contacts = response.data;
                console.log("chatapp1: " + this.contacts[0].name);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            });
    },
    methods: {
        startConversationWith(contact) {
            axios.get(`/officer/conversation/${contact.id}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.message = response.data;
                    this.selectedContact = contact;
                    console.log("chatapp: " + this.selectedContact.name);
                });
        },
        saveNewMessage(message) {
            this.messages.push(message);
        },
        handleIncoming(message) {
            if (this.selectedContact && message.from === this.selectedContact.id) {
                this.saveNewMessage(message);
                return;
            }
            this.updateUnreadCount(message.from_contact, false);
        },
        updateUnreadCount(contact, reset) {
            this.contacts = this.contacts.map((single) => {
                if (single.id !== contact.id) {
                    return single;
                }
                if (reset)
                    single.unread = 0;
                else
                    single.unread += 1;
                return single;
            })
        }
    },
    components: {Conversation, ContactsList}
}
```

**Conversation.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="conversation">
    <h1>{{ contact ? contact.name : 'Select a Contact' }}</h1>
    <MessagesFeed :contact="contact" :messages="messages"/>
    <MessageComposer @send="sendMessage"/>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import MessagesFeed from './MessageFeed';
import MessageComposer from './MessageComposer';
export default {
    props: {
        contact: {
            type: Object,
            default: null
        },
        messages: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log("conversation: "+this.contact);
    },
    methods: {
        sendMessage(text) {
            if (!this.contact) {
                return;
            }
            console.log(text);
            axios.post('/conversation/send', {
                contact_id: this.contact.id,
                text: text
            }).then((response) => {
                this.$emit('new', response.data);
            })
        }
    },
    components: {MessagesFeed, MessageComposer}
}
```

**MessageFeed.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="feed" ref="feed">
    <ul v-if="contact">
        <li v-for="message in messages" :class="`message${message.to == contact.id ? 'sent' : 'received'}`"
            :key="message.id">
            <div class="text">
                {{message.text}}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        contact: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },
        messages: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        scrollToBottom() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.$refs.feed.scrollTop = this.$refs.feed.scrollHeight - this.$refs.feed.clientHeight;
            }, 1);
        }
    },
    watch: {
        contact(contact) {
            this.scrollToBottom();
        },
        messages(messages) {
            this.scrollToBottom();
        }
    }
}
```

please, let me know what am I missing here.

Comment: Are you sure that this error message is not from initial the selectedContect state which is equals to null?

Comment: I am thinking it is, because I put two print statements, one in ChatApp.vue and other one in Conversation,vue, the later got printed out first which is weird, or to me at least it is, anyways, isn't it should Mount the ChatApp first and then other components so that if we are passing variables it should recognize them

Comment: You can try <Conversation v-if="selectedContect" to show component only when selectedContect if loaded and assigned.

Comment: It looks like you don't receive any contact from the ContactsList. In the startConversationWith method, could you console.log(contact)? And/Or provide the code of the ContactsList component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue.
This was due to axios.get() response thing. It was fetching data from database after a couple of minutes and the Conversation.vue and ContactList.vue were mounting immediately so they were not getting data.
With the help of my friend, it was fixed by loading the component only when axios have got all the contactlist from database and the very first contact have been passed to the Conversation.vue component i.e using v-if property of component.

Answer (score 0):

Because you konfigurated it to be an Object but you declared it on the initial state as `null`

```
  selectedContact: null
```

That should be an `object`

It should look something like this i guess:

```
  selectedContact: {
       id:0
  }
```

Comment: `officer.js?id=129a142a656d58ac6230:31472 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "contact". Expected Object, got Function 
found in
---> <Conversation> at resources/js/officer/components/Conversation.vue
       <ChatApp> at resources/js/officer/components/ChatApp.vue
         <Root>`

The error

Comment: The error is clear: `Expected Object, got Function` you pass an function instead of an object.

Comment: I tried the second one and it does not print anything on console. it just prints `conversation: [object Object]`

Comment: I tried the first solution you gave and then this error came up